# The import libraries problem "Recognised but unhandled machine type (0x8664) in Import Library Format archive"

Tags: c++, netbeans, armadillo

I tried to implement my work using netbeans, armadillo and their libraries. When the code was build, the compiler given the massage below:

```
    mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-Linux
g++    -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/boussinesqv2 build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o -L. blas_win64_MT.dll lapack_win64_MT.dll blas_win64_MT.a lapack_win64_MT.a
/usr/bin/ld: blas_win64_MT.a(blas_win64_MT.dll): Recognised but unhandled machine type (0x8664) in Import Library Format archive
/usr/bin/ld: blas_win64_MT.a(blas_win64_MT.dll): Recognised but unhandled machine type (0x8664) in Import Library Format archive
/usr/bin/ld: lapack_win64_MT.a(lapack_win64_MT.dll): Recognised but unhandled machine type (0x8664) in Import Library Format archive
/usr/bin/ld: lapack_win64_MT.a(lapack_win64_MT.dll): Recognised but unhandled machine type (0x8664) in Import Library Format archive
/usr/bin/ld: lapack_win64_MT.a(lapack_win64_MT.dll): Recognised but unhandled machine type (0x8664) in Import Library Format archive
/usr/bin/ld: lapack_win64_MT.a(lapack_win64_MT.dll): Recognised but unhandled machine type (0x8664) in Import Library Format archive
/usr/bin/ld: lapack_win64_MT.a(lapack_win64_MT.dll): Recognised but unhandled machine type (0x8664) in Import Library Format archive
/usr/bin/ld: lapack_win64_MT.a(lapack_win64_MT.dll): Recognised but unhandled machine type (0x8664) in Import Library Format archive
/usr/bin/ld: lapack_win64_MT.a(lapack_win64_MT.dll): Recognised but unhandled machine type (0x8664) in Import Library Format archive
/usr/bin/ld: lapack_win64_MT.a(lapack_win64_MT.dll): Recognised but unhandled machine type (0x8664) in Import Library Format archive
/usr/bin/ld: lapack_win64_MT.a(lapack_win64_MT.dll): Recognised but unhandled machine type (0x8664) in Import Library Format archive
/usr/bin/ld: lapack_win64_MT.a(lapack_win64_MT.dll): Recognised but unhandled machine type (0x8664) in Import Library Format archive
/usr/bin/ld: lapack_win64_MT.a(lapack_win64_MT.dll): Recognised but unhandled machine type (0x8664) in Import Library Format archive
/usr/bin/ld: dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/boussinesqv2: Unable to sort relocs - they are of an unknown size
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/nutthavuth/NetBeansProjects/BoussinesqV2'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/nutthavuth/NetBeansProjects/BoussinesqV2'

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2s)
```

After that, i decide to ran the code. The segfault was occurred as

```
RUN FINISHED; Segmentation fault; core dumped; real time: 4s; user: 80ms; system: 4s
```

The following picture may be help 
[c++ compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8U0t.jpg),  [linker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntSh5.jpg)

Do you have an idea for this problem. T^T

Comment: Looks like you are running on Linux but are using the Windows libraries. Try building as instructed in the Armadillo doc: g++ prog.cpp -o prog -O2 -I /home/blah/armadillo-7.600.2/include -DARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER -lblas -llapack

Comment: Thank you!! Claes Rolen. I have stuck this problem for 3 days. After i see your comment, I solve this problem by using LAPACK and BLAS from linux library instead and it's work. Thanks again ^^